# Where is Dakota?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, static-shock

I've been watching *Static Shock* again and I was wondering the same thing I wonder every time I watch it:

**Where is Dakota located in the United States?**

The wiki says it's somewhere in the Midwestern United States but doesn't give a specific state. I tried checking *The Atlas of The DC Universe* released for the *DC Heroes 2nd Edition* RPG but Dakota isn't mentioned due to the fact that the book was released in 1990 and Milestone Comics, the company that originally used Dakota as a setting, was founded in 1993. There doesn't seem to be an updated version of the book for later editions, nor is Dakota mentioned in the *DC Animated Universe Sourcebook* for *DC Heroes 5th edition*.

ome DC cities are obvious in where they're located, like Teen Titan's Jump City is clearly San Francisco, but others like Dakota don't have enough obvious landmarks to find where they may be located.

So, what state is Dakota located in and around what part of that state?

Comment: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Dakota_City/Gallery?file=Dakota_City_001.jpg

Comment: 1 West 72nd St, just off Central Park West. ):)

Comment: @Valorum I appreciate the image, but it doesn't seem to line up with actual US maps and isn't divided into states itself. From what I can tell that dot places it either in Illinois or Indiana, or on the borders of both states.

Comment: @Spencer that's an apartment, not a city.

Comment: @Demon that is the address of The Dakota.  Yes, it is an apartment building.  I did not notice that Spencer put that in as an *answer*...

Answer (score 4):

### Indiana, most likely.

If we look at the map that Valorum linked:

[image]

The most important reference is it is very nearly due south of the bottom tip of Lake Michigan.

If you super impose that map over a real one (you have to hunt around for the right kind of shape (DC might not care about social equality when it comes to [cartography](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMfXVWFBrVo))) you find this is likely in the Terre Haute / Bloomington / Indianapolis region are of Indiana.

[image]